# How to get product details along with transaction id after payment is done

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer

I am using magento 1.8.
My requirement is..

**I need to add some product information into my custom table after the payment is done.[when customer redirect from paypal to the our website store]**

This table need to be contain product details, customer information, transaction information.
I think writing observer is good for this,
So **I am not getting which observer method I need to use which is suitable for above requirement**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could either go for the `sales_order_invoice_pay` or the `sales_order_invoice_save_after` event. Depending on the payment module you're using the `sales_order_invoice_pay` event might not get triggered correctly but the `invoice_save_after` event is always triggered when an invoice is created